# Displaying "Changelog" on First Launch

Tags: vb.net

I have an application that checks for updates on launch. I want the app to pop-up a window with a changelog on ONLY the FIRST launch after it updates. Then after it is displayed it is never displayed again until the next update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
If My.Application.Deployment.IsFirstRun Then
    ShowChangeLog()
End If
```

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.isfirstrun.aspx

Comment: I think that will only be True on absolute first run of the application. He's talking about when the application updates and then is run to show the change log. My recommendation would be to keep a configuration file like most applications do.

Comment: @kellax -- Shouldn't this work tho, according to the docs it says : this property is reset whenever the user upgrades from one version to the next. -- In all, a config file is probably the best way to go, just saw this and thought it may solve the issue at hand.

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone. I am not familiar with config files, I've kinda taught myself aside form a local college course. I'm googling it now but any info that could point me in the right direction would be great. Thanks!

Comment: DreamInCode has a nice post about it: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/72654-using-settings/ -- Check it out